# How can I load advertisements after content?

Tags: javascript, html

sometimes my ads causing my site loding very slowly and content is not showing up. i tried this for loading the top ad after the content but it did not work;

```
<code><div id=”top_ad_loader” style=”display:none;”>adcode</div><script type=”text/javascript”>document.getElementById(“top_ad”).innerHTML =document.getElementById(“top_ad_loader”).innerHTML</script>
```

any ideas?
thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try moving the HTML for the advertisements to below the HTML for the content? What happened?

Comment: `<div>`s that aren't displayed are still loaded. Use something like jQuery to create the whole `top_ad_loader` div after the page finishes loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply load the ads inside iframes. They won't slow down the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Loading 3rd party ads after the page is loaded is not an easy task. Because most ads use `document.write()` to add their content. When document.write is used after the site is loaded causes the whole page to go blank.

One thing to do is to overwrite document.write on top of the page and manipulate the content yourself.

Example:

```
// top of the page
var adContent = [];
    document.write = function (a){
    adContent.push(a);
}
```

Now all your ads data is in the `adContent` array, you can check the content and append it to the write part.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you tried - innerHTML on a script <strike>tag</strike> - just won't work.

Instead, you would need to add the script dynamically **after** the page loads:

```
var newScript=document.createElement("script");
newScript.src="script.js";
document.head.appendChild(newScript);
```

Unfortunately often this won't work directly on the main page because the ad needs to run at a specific location. In this case, a workaround is to use an iframe. This is what I do in the right hand side of [this page](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/).